# Sorting lines in one file given the order in another file

Tags: bash, file, sorting

Given a file1:

```
13 a b c d
5 f a c d
7 d c g a
14 a v s d
```

and a file2:

```
7 x
5 c
14 a
13 i
```

I would like to sort file1 considering the same order of the first column in file2, so that the output should be:

```
7 d c g a
5 f a c d
14 a v s d
13 a b c d
```

Is it possible to do this in bash or should I use some "higher" language like python?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `awk` to put the line number from `file2` as an extra column in front of `file1`. Sort the result by that column. Then remove that prefix column

```
awk 'FNR == NR { lineno[$1] = NR; next}
     {print lineno[$1], $0;}' file2 file1 | sort -k 1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution

`for S in $(cat file2 | awk '{print $1}'); do grep $S file1; done`