# Sorting lines in a file using a specified order in another file

Tags: bash, file, sorting

Given a file1

```
a b c d
e f h
n o p q
i j k
l m
```

and another file2

```
3
1
0
1
2
```

I would like to sort file1 in the order given in file2. Output should be:

```
n o p q
e f h
i j k
l m
a b c d
```

Basically, how can I add the file2 in front of file1 as a prefix column, and sort by that column, then remove the prefix column?

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180209/sorting-lines-in-one-file-given-the-order-in-another-file) is a very close match, but doesn't exactly answer my question.

Comment: You should mention that file 2 should be orderd ascending, and that file 1 should use the same order. I had to read the other question in order to understand how you get that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`paste` is your friend:

```
paste f2 f1 | sort | cut -d$'\t' -f2-
```

In steps:

```
$ paste f2 f1        # join files
3   a b c d
1   e f h
0   n o p q
1   i j k
2   l m
$ paste f2 f1 | sort # sort them
0   n o p q
1   e f h
1   i j k
2   l m
3   a b c d
$ paste f2 f1 | sort | cut -d$'\t' -f2-  # remove 1st column
n o p q
e f h
i j k
l m
a b c d
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! What happens if I have 2 lines as header in file1? (no headers in file2) How can I ignore them in the paste / sort ?

Comment: You can say `paste f2 <(tail -n +3 f1)` to get from 3rd line in `file1`.